# Scala Int overflow

Tags: scala

Can anyone please help me to understand that why Int type overflow result is not consistent with higher numbers. Sometime it is positive, sometime negative and finally converge to zero.

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

object FactorialExample {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    (1 to 100).foreach(i => println(s"Factorial of ${i} is " + factorial(i)))
  }

  def factorial(i: Int): Int = {
    @tailrec
    def fact(i: Int, acc: Int): Int = {
      if (i <= 0) acc
      else fact(i - 1, acc * i)
    }
    fact(i, 1)
  }
}
```

Comment: `Int` is [signed 32bit number](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/Int.html) so it [cannot store 100!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit#Range_for_storing_integers)

Comment: I do understand that its overflow situation but my question was once overflow situation comes into picture compiler should throw a number by which user should be aware that its garbage and need to use other data type.

Comment: Actually, integer overflow is not garbage and is a feature that is used a lot in security. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913618/how-is-integer-overflow-exploitable

Comment: "I do understand that its overflow situation" perfect. "my question was 
once overflow situation comes into picture compiler should throw a number" that's not a question, that's your opinion, and it doesn't make much sense (what does "throwing a number" ever mean?) If you want to ask why integer overflow doesn't result in an exception, just ask that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why Int type overflow result is not consistent with higher numbers. Sometime it is positive, sometime negative and finally converge to zero.

This is just how overflowing int types behave. You can read more at e.g. [Modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) or  [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). Do you have a specific question?

> I do understand that its overflow situation but my question was once overflow situation comes into picture compiler should throw a number by which user should be aware that its garbage and need to use other data type

This is answered at [Why, In Java arithmetic, overflow or underflow will never throw an Exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085286/why-in-java-arithmetic-overflow-or-underflow-will-never-throw-an-exception)

Answer (score 8):

As others have pointed out, *Scala*, and *Java*, do not perform overflow checking on integer values by default. (I agree that quietly overflowing a value can result in unexpected—and unwanted—behavior, and many very subtle bugs.) However, all is not lost. `java.lang.Math` has static methods (`addExact`, `incrementExact`, `multiplyExact`, `subtractExact`, etc.) that will throw an `ArithmeticException` if a calculation overflows the underlying type. For example:

```scala
scala> def factorial(n: Int): Int = {
     |   if(n <= 1) 1
     |   else Math.multiplyExact(n, factorial(n - 1))
     | }
factorial: (n: Int)Int

scala> factorial(12)
res0: Int = 479001600

scala> factorial(13)
java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow
  at java.lang.Math.multiplyExact(Math.java:867)
  at .factorial(<console>:13)
  ... 28 elided
```

This version isn't tail recursive, and throwing exceptions violates *functional programming* principles (a better approach is to return a type that encapsulates possible errors, such as a `Try[Int]` or `Either[Throwable, Int]`), but it will detect and report overflows of the `Int` type. Refer to [`java.lang.Math`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html) for further details.

For example, here's a *functional* version that will not exhaust the stack:

```scala
scala> import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.annotation.tailrec

scala> import scala.util.Try
import scala.util.Try

scala> def factorial(n: Int): Try[Int] = {
     |   @tailrec
     |   def fact(i: Int, acc: Int): Int = {
     |     if(i <= 1) acc
     |     else fact(i - 1, Math.multiplyExact(i, acc))
     |   }
     |   Try(fact(n, 1))
     | }

scala> factorial(12)
res0: scala.util.Try[Int] = Success(479001600)

scala> factorial(13)
res1: scala.util.Try[Int] = Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow)
```

Regarding the overflowed value: you can regard such results as being effectively random. It is the result of retaining only the right-most 32 bits (the capacity of an `Int` type) of the overflowed result. If the *most significant bit* is set, then this value will be treated as a negative value. (As others have pointed out, see [*Two's Complement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) for a more detailed explanation of how `Int` bit patterns are interpreted.) While it would depend upon the calculation you're performing, the results would not *converge* on zero in the general case.

For example, `factorial(13)` is the lowest argument value that causes an `Int` overflow. Without using `Math.multiplyExact`, your original function would return the value `1932053504`—which is not *obviously* wrong, unfortunately. If we use `Long` instead of `Int`, we can calculate this result exactly as `6227020800`. But let's look at these numbers in their binary representations:

```scala
scala> 1932053504.toBinaryString
res0: String = 1110011001010001100110000000000

scala> 6227020800L.toBinaryString
res1: String = 101110011001010001100110000000000
```

The right-most 32 bits have the same values! (Note that leading zeros are omitted.) However, the `Long` representation has an additional bit, which cannot be stored in the `Int` representation, and that makes all the difference. Unfortunately, the recursive algorithm (`n! = n * (n - 1)!`) means that these errors are compounded once we get an overflow, meaning that, for argument values higher than 13, we start multiplying overflowed values, resulting in total garbage, and further destroying any patterns in the overflowed value. In particular, once a factorial is calculated as zero, all subsequent values will clearly be zero too.

Comment: Good answer. You obviously have more patience than I had when I wrote mine :-)

Comment: @Rich. Thanks! But sometimes a more concise answer does the trick... ;-)