# using built in tensor functions with R

Tags: r, tensorflow

In R, I have been trying to use Tensorflow math functions. My issue is I can't figure out how to enter arguments into the tensorflow functions like you can with Python.

For example, how can I do the `tensorflowdot` function?

```
x = tf$constant(c(1, 2, 3))
y = tf$constant(c(9, 8, 7))
tf$tensordot(x, y, axes = 1)
```

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  TypeError: Cannot convert 1.0 to EagerTensor of dtype int32
```

I can reproduce the output of `tensordot` manually, but I want to use the built in

```
tf$reduce_sum(x * y)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `axes` value is parsed as a float, not an integer.  Fixing it as an integer resolves the error:

```r
> tf$tensordot(x, y, axes = 1L) 
tf.Tensor(46.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

This is related to [how R defines numeric data types](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32401713/2799941).

```
is.integer(1) # FALSE
is.double(1) # TRUE

is.integer(1L) # TRUE
is.double(1L) # FALSE
```