# R session abort during data.matrix transformation

Tags: r, matrix

I have this big binary data.table:

```
> str(mat)
Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':  262561 obs. of  10615 variables:
 $ 1001682: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 1001990: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 1002541: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 1002790: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 1003312: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ 1004403: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

There are somewhere 1 (it's not full of zeros). And I'm trying to convert it to `data.matrix` by just writing `mat <- data.matrix(mat)` but R session always abort. Is it a problem with my computer? Should I try some high performance computer? Or is there some other way to do this? I need it in `data.matrix`.

I'm using macbook pro early 2015 with 2.7 GHz Intel Core i5 and 8Gm DDR3.

Comment: "I need it in data.matrix." Really? It rather looks like you should make it a sparse matrix (see package Matrix).

Comment: 8 * 262561 * 10615 / 1024^3 ~ 21GB. How can you have this in memory with only 8GB? Does `data.table` already know it is sparse? Or is it some lazyness of R?

Comment: @Roland This really looks like sparse matrix, but it's because of data which I use. I'm trying to write general code so the `mat` should sometimes contain more 1 than 0.

Comment: That wouldn't be a problem for a sparse matrix structure ...

Comment: @Roland ok, but how should I make sparse matrix from data.table? I need to have the values "1001682", "1001990" etc. in colnames. I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207850/create-sparse-matrix-from-a-data-frame) for some hint but it didn't help.
I can store `colnames(mat)` and just use values from `mat`, but I don't understand well the help for `sparseMatrix`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is more efficient that Roland's method, but it produces the same matrix and does not require a reshape of the data. It does require essentially the same `lapply` as in [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45839395/na-replace-function-in-r/45842767#45842767) to the OP, which she described as slow.  Using the `data.table` constructed in Roland's answer.

```
library(Matrix)

# get positions of non-zero values in data.table
myRows <- lapply(DT, function(x) which(x != 0))

# build sparse matrix
DT <- sparseMatrix(i = unlist(myRows), # row positions of non zero values
                   j = rep(seq_along(myRows), lengths(myRows)), # column positions
                   dims = c(nrow(DT), ncol(DT))) # dimension of matrix
```

This returns

```
DT
3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "lgCMatrix"

[1,] . | . | .
[2,] | . . . .
[3,] | | | . |
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can convert the data.table to a sparse matrix:

```
library(data.table)
library(Matrix)
DT <- fread("A B C D E
            0 1 0 1 0
            1 0 0 0 0
            1 1 1 0 1")

ncol <- length(DT)
nrow <- nrow(DT)
dimnames <- names(DT)

DT <- melt(DT)
inds <- DT[, which(as.logical(value))]
i <- (inds -1) %% nrow + 1
j <- (inds - 1) %/% nrow + 1

DT <- DT[value == 1]
DT <- sparseMatrix(i = i, j = j, x = TRUE, dims = c(nrow, ncol), dimnames = list(NULL, dimnames))
#3 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "lgCMatrix"
#     A B C D E
#[1,] . | . | .
#[2,] | . . . .
#[3,] | | | . |
```

It is unclear what you want to do with the data, but a sparse matrix is the most memory efficient data structure here. Of course, functions you plan to use must be able to deal with such a structure.

**Edit:**

OP wants to calculate the cosine similarity.

```
library(qlcMatrix)
cosSparse(DT)
#5 x 5 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"
#          A         B         C         D         E
#A 1.0000000 0.5000000 0.7071068 .         0.7071068
#B 0.5000000 1.0000000 0.7071068 0.7071068 0.7071068
#C 0.7071068 0.7071068 1.0000000 .         1.0000000
#D .         0.7071068 .         1.0000000 .        
#E 0.7071068 0.7071068 1.0000000 .         1.0000000
```

Comment: so the output will really look like dots and lines? .... after I get my data in form of some matrix I need to compute cosine similarity, that's why I need it in form of data.matrix (or something similar) so I'm not sure this sparse matrix is right input for `cosine` function. (maybe I should mentioned it before)

Comment: Please don't confuse print output with the internal structure. Anyway, see https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qlcMatrix/versions/0.9.5/topics/cosSparse

Comment: I just have a time to try it and I have one question: Is there any way how to transform this similarity sparse matrix back to ordinary matrix which will look exacatly like your print output but instead of . there will be 0.

Comment: simply use as.matrix, but that will increase memory demand, possibly strongly increase it.

Comment: I was just writing here: when I try as.matrix the R quit with no warning or "R session aborted"

Comment: I realize that I will probably use the sparse matrix and I will not try transform it back.

Comment: Why do you care how zero is plotted anyway?

Comment: That isn't the problem. I was running some for loop and it didn't work so I was thinking it was because I originaly use ordinary matrix in this for loop. But then I realized that I don't use matrix but data frame, so I can't call the rows from sparse matrix like [[..]].