# Sum() in dplyr and aggregate: NA values

Tags: r, sum, dplyr, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I have a dataset with about 3,000 rows. The data can be accessed via https://pastebin.com/i4dYCUQX

Problem: NA results in the output, though there appear to be no NA in the data. Here is what happens when I try to sum the total value in each category of a column via dplyr or aggregate:

```
example <- read.csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/i4dYCUQX", header=TRUE, sep=",")
example

# dplyr
example %>% group_by(size) %>% summarize_at(vars(volume), funs(sum))

Out:
# A tibble: 4 x 2
         size    volume
       <fctr>     <int>
1 Extra Large        NA
2       Large        NA
3      Medium 937581572
4       Small        NA

# aggregate
aggregate(volume ~ size, data=example, FUN=sum)

Out:
         size    volume
1 Extra Large        NA
2       Large        NA
3      Medium 937581572
4       Small        NA
```

When trying to access the value via `colSums`, it seems to work:

```
# Colsums
small <- example %>% filter(size == "Small")
colSums(small["volume"], na.rm = FALSE, dims = 1)

Out:
volume 
3869267348
```

**Can anyone imagine what the issue could be?**

Comment: Well, I belive the _Warning messages_ are rather informative: `[...] integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that, running your example, I get:

```r
example <- read.csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/i4dYCUQX", header=TRUE, sep=",")
# dplyr
example %>% group_by(size) %>% summarize_at(vars(volume), funs(sum))
#> Warning in summarise_impl(.data, dots): integer overflow - use
#> sum(as.numeric(.))

#> Warning in summarise_impl(.data, dots): integer overflow - use
#> sum(as.numeric(.))

#> Warning in summarise_impl(.data, dots): integer overflow - use
#> sum(as.numeric(.))
#> # A tibble: 4 Ã— 2
#>          size    volume
#>        <fctr>     <int>
#> 1 Extra Large        NA
#> 2       Large        NA
#> 3      Medium 937581572
#> 4       Small        NA
```

which clearly states that you're sums are overflowing the integer type. If we do as the warning message suggests, we can convert the integers to numerics and then sum:

```r
example <- read.csv("https://pastebin.com/raw/i4dYCUQX", header=TRUE, sep=",")
# dplyr
example %>% group_by(size) %>% summarize_at(vars(volume), funs(sum(as.numeric(.))))
#> # A tibble: 4 Ã— 2
#>          size      volume
#>        <fctr>       <dbl>
#> 1 Extra Large  3609485056
#> 2       Large 11435467097
#> 3      Medium   937581572
#> 4       Small  3869267348
```

here the `funs(sum)` has been replaced by `funs(sum(as.numeric(.))` which is the same, executing `sum` on each group but converting to `numeric` first.

Comment: Thank you, that helped! So, there's a limit for ints?

Answer (score 1):

its because value is an integer and not numeric

```
example$volume <- as.numeric(example$volume)

aggregate(volume ~ size, data=example, FUN=sum)

         size      volume
1 Extra Large  3609485056
2       Large 11435467097
3      Medium   937581572
4       Small  3869267348
```

For more check here:

[What is integer overflow in R and how can it happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804779/what-is-integer-overflow-in-r-and-how-can-it-happen)

Comment: Thank you, that helped, too!