# Error when generating histogram in R

Tags: r

I have a text file containing:

```
Tue Feb 11 12:19:39 +0000 2014
Tue Feb 11 12:19:56 +0000 2014
Tue Feb 11 12:20:04 +0000 2014
```

and i read it into r

```
dataset <- read.csv("Time.txt")
```

and in order for R to recognise the timestamps in the file, i write:

```
time <- strptime(dataset[,1], format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
```

and whenever i try to plot a histogram with:

```
hist(time, breaks = 100)
```

it produces an error together with a generated histogram

```
In breaks[-1L] + breaks[-nB] : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

What could be the issue that is prompting this error?

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked what could be causing the error here it is:

The error is created when the `hist.default` function calculates the midpoints of the histogram. This vector `mids <- 0.5 * (breaks[-1L] + breaks[-nB])` calculates the halfway point between each break. The issue arises because the breaks are generated as integers:

If the argument `breaks` is `numeric` and `length == 1` then the `hist.default` function (which is called by `hist.POSIXt`) creates a vector of `breaks` based on the range of `x` and the number of breaks. This is done using the `pretty` command. For reasons I have not looked into too closely, if `breaks` is small enough that `pretty(range(x),n=breaks, min.n = 1)` returns only one of each value e.g.:

```r
pretty(range(x), n = 35, min.n = 1)
#[1] 1392121179 1392121180 1392121181 1392121182 1392121183 1392121184
#[7] 1392121185 1392121186 1392121187 1392121188 1392121189 1392121190
#[13] 1392121191 1392121192 1392121193 1392121194 1392121195 1392121196
#[19] 1392121197 1392121198 1392121199 1392121200 1392121201 1392121202
#[25] 1392121203 1392121204
```

then the output is an `integer` type. If however, the number of breaks is larger and some of the outputs are duplicated:

```r
pretty(range(x), n = 36, min.n = 1)
# [1] 1392121179 1392121180 1392121180 1392121181 1392121181 1392121182
# [7] 1392121182 1392121183 1392121183 1392121184 1392121184 1392121185
#[13] 1392121185 1392121186 1392121186 1392121187 1392121187 1392121188
#[19] 1392121188 1392121189 1392121189 1392121190 1392121190 1392121191
#[25] 1392121191 1392121192 1392121192 1392121193 1392121193 1392121194
#[31] 1392121194 1392121195 1392121195 1392121196 1392121196 1392121197
#[37] 1392121197 1392121198 1392121198 1392121199 1392121199 1392121200
#[43] 1392121200 1392121201 1392121201 1392121202 1392121202 1392121203
#[49] 1392121203 1392121204 1392121204
```

then the output is `numeric`.

Because R uses 32 bit integer types and `POSIXt` integers are large numbers, adding two `POSIXt` integers results in an overflow that R can't handle and returns `NA`. When `pretty` returns numeric, this is not a problem.

See also: [What is integer overflow in R and how can it happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804779/what-is-integer-overflow-in-r-and-how-can-it-happen)

In practice, all this means is that, if you print out the `hist` structure returned, all of your `mids` values will be `NA` but I don't think it actually affects the plotting of the histogram. Thus it is only a warning.

EDIT:
`pretty` internally uses `seq.int`

Answer (score 0):

In my environement, it does not generate any errors.

```
dataset <- read.csv("Time.txt", header = F)
time <- strptime(dataset[,1], format = "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %z %Y")
hist(as.numeric(time), breaks = 100)
```

Perhaps if you just convert time into numeric as above, error will disappear. Then, it is straightforward to change the x-axis of the histogram.

EDIT : The `ggplot2` should not face this issue and is much simpler and modern :

```
ggplot(dataset) + geom_histogram(aes(x = V1), stat = "count", bins = 100)
```

Where V1 is the default name of the unique column of `dataset` created by `read.csv()`.

Comment: Like you, I did not get the warning with the data above but I could replicate it with fewer breaks. I'm guessing the problem is related to having too few breaks and the dataset in the question is not the full set.