# why plotting datetime histogram cause NAs produced by integer overflow

Tags: r, histogram

I have the following code

```
a=c('2017-05-15 09:28:38 GMT', '2017-05-16 14:02:19 GMT', '2017-05-20 03:02:49 GMT', '2017-05-21 17:40:47 GMT', '2017-05-23 20:23:47 GMT', '2017-05-24 21:01:07 GMT', '2017-05-26 12:50:18 GMT', '2017-05-27 05:39:55 GMT', '2017-05-30 03:56:31 GMT', '2017-06-01 15:44:49 GMT', '2017-06-02 17:07:06 GMT', '2017-06-05 19:01:09 GMT', '2017-06-07 16:14:02 GMT', '2017-06-08 16:51:22 GMT', '2017-06-11 14:51:42 GMT', '2017-06-11 19:41:17 GMT', '2017-06-14 20:59:10 GMT', '2017-06-17 18:32:42 GMT', '2017-06-17 19:13:10 GMT', '2017-06-24 22:14:49 GMT', '2017-06-27 20:50:54 GMT', '2017-06-27 23:42:34 GMT', '2017-07-06 17:36:37 GMT', '2017-07-10 23:39:39 GMT', '2017-07-18 03:05:25 GMT', '2017-07-20 16:59:55 GMT', '2017-07-24 03:57:07 GMT', '2017-08-13 20:15:11 GMT', '2016-11-21 15:35:23 GMT', '2016-11-23 20:24:24 GMT', '2016-11-24 16:30:47 GMT', '2016-11-24 21:54:08 GMT', '2016-12-02 17:07:12 GMT', '2016-12-05 19:10:26 GMT', '2016-12-06 11:00:45 GMT', '2016-12-06 23:35:13 GMT', '2016-12-09 00:58:07 GMT', '2016-12-19 01:41:55 GMT', '2016-12-19 21:58:19 GMT', '2016-12-22 16:42:25 GMT', '2016-12-23 05:50:15 GMT', '2016-12-24 10:10:42 GMT', '2016-12-24 13:51:36 GMT', '2016-12-25 12:53:51 GMT', '2016-12-27 21:26:21 GMT', '2017-01-04 07:37:26 GMT', '2017-01-04 15:08:49 GMT', '2017-01-05 16:10:41 GMT', '2017-01-06 04:19:33 GMT', '2017-01-06 23:18:08 GMT', '2017-01-09 16:52:27 GMT', '2017-01-12 18:20:21 GMT', '2017-01-13 10:49:40 GMT', '2017-01-13 18:54:39 GMT', '2017-01-22 13:25:32 GMT', '2017-01-23 06:31:25 GMT', '2017-01-23 19:26:42 GMT', '2017-01-23 21:17:51 GMT', '2017-01-25 07:21:29 GMT', '2017-01-25 19:13:47 GMT', '2017-01-28 11:41:20 GMT', '2017-01-29 07:48:43 GMT', '2017-01-30 21:31:50 GMT', '2017-01-31 08:42:57 GMT', '2017-02-03 22:37:24 GMT', '2017-02-04 15:33:58 GMT', '2017-02-04 19:22:24 GMT', '2017-02-07 04:14:46 GMT', '2017-02-09 02:42:09 GMT', '2017-02-11 18:26:45 GMT', '2017-02-12 14:15:23 GMT', '2017-02-16 12:35:03 GMT', '2017-02-16 21:46:43 GMT', '2017-02-20 12:30:13 GMT', '2017-02-20 14:22:10 GMT', '2017-02-22 08:53:34 GMT', '2017-02-22 19:56:49 GMT', '2017-02-22 22:43:13 GMT', '2017-02-22 23:14:48 GMT', '2017-02-27 14:19:04 GMT', '2017-02-28 18:21:30 GMT', '2017-03-02 19:06:14 GMT', '2017-03-02 22:29:09 GMT', '2017-03-03 04:39:49 GMT', '2017-03-03 22:33:46 GMT', '2017-03-07 06:47:34 GMT', '2017-03-07 09:25:16 GMT', '2017-03-08 12:44:21 GMT', '2017-03-08 23:40:59 GMT', '2017-03-10 21:39:40 GMT', '2017-03-10 22:57:22 GMT', '2017-03-12 19:10:41 GMT', '2017-03-19 20:39:21 GMT', '2017-03-20 19:48:41 GMT', '2017-03-20 20:44:55 GMT', '2017-03-22 08:48:24 GMT', '2017-03-22 09:03:59 GMT', '2017-03-23 23:33:34 GMT', '2017-03-24 14:53:31 GMT', '2017-03-27 23:42:08 GMT', '2017-03-28 14:41:53 GMT', '2017-03-30 15:54:30 GMT', '2017-04-04 08:37:43 GMT', '2017-04-06 12:14:19 GMT', '2017-04-07 01:02:23 GMT', '2017-04-08 01:09:43 GMT', '2017-04-12 14:24:11 GMT', '2017-04-13 11:06:43 GMT', '2017-04-15 03:50:58 GMT', '2017-04-18 23:16:03 GMT', '2017-04-19 11:36:27 GMT', '2017-04-19 23:14:05 GMT', '2017-04-21 21:57:46 GMT', '2017-04-23 01:17:12 GMT', '2017-04-24 19:08:23 GMT', '2017-04-24 20:00:19 GMT', '2017-04-24 23:06:57 GMT', '2017-04-26 13:14:51 GMT', '2017-04-27 16:48:10 GMT', '2017-04-28 10:26:11 GMT', '2017-05-01 11:21:27 GMT', '2017-05-01 18:37:55 GMT', '2017-05-02 20:36:20 GMT', '2017-05-08 19:02:54 GMT', '2017-05-10 16:00:20 GMT', '2017-05-10 21:36:27 GMT', '2017-05-18 13:16:55 GMT', '2017-05-19 22:55:38 GMT', '2017-05-21 09:10:22 GMT', '2017-05-22 06:17:33 GMT', '2017-05-22 08:34:26 GMT', '2017-05-28 21:09:29 GMT', '2017-05-29 14:40:20 GMT', '2017-05-30 02:17:38 GMT', '2017-06-01 20:41:41 GMT', '2017-06-03 17:33:17 GMT', '2017-06-05 12:13:21 GMT', '2017-06-05 12:16:25 GMT', '2017-06-05 20:28:17 GMT', '2017-06-10 14:19:52 GMT', '2017-06-10 21:29:37 GMT', '2017-06-16 07:26:04 GMT', '2017-06-17 03:31:37 GMT', '2017-06-19 12:12:42 GMT', '2017-06-20 01:42:28 GMT', '2017-07-01 18:35:31 GMT', '2017-07-02 23:14:19 GMT', '2017-07-11 14:29:22 GMT', '2017-07-17 18:18:19 GMT', '2017-07-25 14:37:00 GMT', '2009-08-17 10:34:59 GMT')
a=c(a,'2010-03-02 07:41:10 GMT', '2010-07-02 14:43:22 GMT', '2011-04-16 13:27:25 GMT', '2011-05-25 11:57:45 GMT', '2011-08-17 14:37:46 GMT', '2011-09-20 14:42:01 GMT', '2011-10-17 21:34:30 GMT', '2011-11-01 11:08:02 GMT', '2011-11-16 18:34:25 GMT', '2011-12-05 00:20:26 GMT', '2012-01-06 05:35:32 GMT', '2012-02-18 13:30:37 GMT', '2012-02-20 18:50:31 GMT', '2012-03-23 17:33:06 GMT', '2012-03-25 15:54:29 GMT', '2012-03-31 11:00:12 GMT', '2012-04-10 18:44:51 GMT', '2012-04-24 08:42:29 GMT', '2012-05-22 16:50:37 GMT', '2012-06-11 13:49:18 GMT', '2012-06-22 16:12:52 GMT', '2012-06-24 15:27:29 GMT', '2012-06-27 12:24:34 GMT', '2012-06-27 19:04:32 GMT', '2012-07-07 22:21:41 GMT', '2012-08-01 02:41:03 GMT', '2012-09-07 20:17:26 GMT', '2012-09-10 08:24:35 GMT', '2012-11-09 14:55:58 GMT', '2012-11-21 01:11:07 GMT', '2012-12-09 15:35:54 GMT', '2012-12-13 22:42:07 GMT', '2012-12-27 00:56:58 GMT', '2013-01-04 09:38:37 GMT', '2013-01-04 18:32:00 GMT', '2013-01-16 21:34:06 GMT', '2013-01-19 12:01:41 GMT', '2013-02-02 18:58:36 GMT', '2013-02-24 19:06:48 GMT', '2013-03-04 07:23:09 GMT', '2013-03-16 19:38:59 GMT', '2013-03-19 20:44:49 GMT', '2013-03-22 05:14:40 GMT', '2013-03-22 09:16:23 GMT', '2013-03-22 23:47:17 GMT', '2013-03-27 19:50:03 GMT', '2013-05-01 21:09:21 GMT', '2013-05-08 12:54:53 GMT', '2013-05-10 09:51:37 GMT', '2013-05-12 11:47:03 GMT')
hist(as.POSIXct(a,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT"), breaks=10)
```

Then I got a warning

```
Error in plot.window(xlim, ylim, "", ...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In n * h : NAs produced by integer overflow
2: In breaks[-1L] + breaks[-nB] : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

Why is this the case?

Even with the following

```
hist(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(a,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT")), breaks=10)
```

I still got the error

```
Warning messages:
1: In n * h : NAs produced by integer overflow
2: In breaks[-1L] + breaks[-nB] : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

Also, a small question on this:

```
> a=c('2017-05-15 09:28:38 GMT', '2017-05-16 14:02:19 GMT', '2017-05-20 03:02:49 GMT', '2017-05-21 17:40:47 GMT', '2017-05-23 20:23:47 GMT', '2017-05-24 21:01:07 GMT', '2017-05-26 12:50:18 GMT', '2017-05-27 05:39:55 GMT', '2017-05-30 03:56:31 GMT', '2017-06-01 15:44:49 GMT', '2017-06-02 17:07:06 GMT', '2017-06-05 19:01:09 GMT', '2017-06-07 16:14:02 GMT', '2017-06-08 16:51:22 GMT', '2017-06-11 14:51:42 GMT', '2017-06-11 19:41:17 GMT', '2017-06-14 20:59:10 GMT', '2017-06-17 18:32:42 GMT', '2017-06-17 19:13:10 GMT', '2017-06-24 22:14:49 GMT', '2017-06-27 20:50:54 GMT', '2017-06-27 23:42:34 GMT', '2017-07-06 17:36:37 GMT', '2017-07-10 23:39:39 GMT', '2017-07-18 03:05:25 GMT', '2017-07-20 16:59:55 GMT', '2017-07-24 03:57:07 GMT', '2017-08-13 20:15:11 GMT', '2016-11-21 15:35:23 GMT', '2016-11-23 20:24:24 GMT', '2016-11-24 16:30:47 GMT', '2016-11-24 21:54:08 GMT', '2016-12-02 17:07:12 GMT', '2016-12-05 19:10:26 GMT', '2016-12-06 11:00:45 GMT', '2016-12-06 23:35:13 GMT', '2016-12-09 00:58:07 GMT', '2016-12-19 01:41:55 GMT', '2016-12-19 21:58:19 GMT', '2016-12-22 16:42:25 GMT', '2016-12-23 05:50:15 GMT', '2016-12-24 10:10:42 GMT', '2016-12-24 13:51:36 GMT', '2016-12-25 12:53:51 GMT', '2016-12-27 21:26:21 GMT', '2017-01-04 07:37:26 GMT', '2017-01-04 15:08:49 GMT', '2017-01-05 16:10:41 GMT', '2017-01-06 04:19:33 GMT', '2017-01-06 23:18:08 GMT', '2017-01-09 16:52:27 GMT', '2017-01-12 18:20:21 GMT', '2017-01-13 10:49:40 GMT', '2017-01-13 18:54:39 GMT', '2017-01-22 13:25:32 GMT', '2017-01-23 06:31:25 GMT', '2017-01-23 19:26:42 GMT', '2017-01-23 21:17:51 GMT', '2017-01-25 07:21:29 GMT', '2017-01-25 19:13:47 GMT', '2017-01-28 11:41:20 GMT', '2017-01-29 07:48:43 GMT', '2017-01-30 21:31:50 GMT', '2017-01-31 08:42:57 GMT', '2017-02-03 22:37:24 GMT', '2017-02-04 15:33:58 GMT', '2017-02-04 19:22:24 GMT', '2017-02-07 04:14:46 GMT', '2017-02-09 02:42:09 GMT', '2017-02-11 18:26:45 GMT', '2017-02-12 14:15:23 GMT', '2017-02-16 12:35:03 GMT', '2017-02-16 21:46:43 GMT', '2017-02-20 12:30:13 GMT', '2017-02-20 14:22:10 GMT', '2017-02-22 08:53:34 GMT', '2017-02-22 19:56:49 GMT', '2017-02-22 22:43:13 GMT', '2017-02-22 23:14:48 GMT', '2017-02-27 14:19:04 GMT', '2017-02-28 18:21:30 GMT', '2017-03-02 19:06:14 GMT', '2017-03-02 22:29:09 GMT', '2017-03-03 04:39:49 GMT', '2017-03-03 22:33:46 GMT', '2017-03-07 06:47:34 GMT', '2017-03-07 09:25:16 GMT', '2017-03-08 12:44:21 GMT', '2017-03-08 23:40:59 GMT', '2017-03-10 21:39:40 GMT', '2017-03-10 22:57:22 GMT', '2017-03-12 19:10:41 GMT', '2017-03-19 20:39:21 GMT', '2017-03-20 19:48:41 GMT', '2017-03-20 20:44:55 GMT', '2017-03-22 08:48:24 GMT', '2017-03-22 09:03:59 GMT', '2017-03-23 23:33:34 GMT', '2017-03-24 14:53:31 GMT', '2017-03-27 23:42:08 GMT', '2017-03-28 14:41:53 GMT', '2017-03-30 15:54:30 GMT', '2017-04-04 08:37:43 GMT', '2017-04-06 12:14:19 GMT', '2017-04-07 01:02:23 GMT', '2017-04-08 01:09:43 GMT', '2017-04-12 14:24:11 GMT', '2017-04-13 11:06:43 GMT', '2017-04-15 03:50:58 GMT', '2017-04-18 23:16:03 GMT', '2017-04-19 11:36:27 GMT', '2017-04-19 23:14:05 GMT', '2017-04-21 21:57:46 GMT', '2017-04-23 01:17:12 GMT', '2017-04-24 19:08:23 GMT', '2017-04-24 20:00:19 GMT', '2017-04-24 23:06:57 GMT', '2017-04-26 13:14:51 GMT', '2017-04-27 16:48:10 GMT', '2017-04-28 10:26:11 GMT', '2017-05-01 11:21:27 GMT', '2017-05-01 18:37:55 GMT', '2017-05-02 20:36:20 GMT', '2017-05-08 19:02:54 GMT', '2017-05-10 16:00:20 GMT', '2017-05-10 21:36:27 GMT', '2017-05-18 13:16:55 GMT', '2017-05-19 22:55:38 GMT', '2017-05-21 09:10:22 GMT', '2017-05-22 06:17:33 GMT', '2017-05-22 08:34:26 GMT', '2017-05-28 21:09:29 GMT', '2017-05-29 14:40:20 GMT', '2017-05-30 02:17:38 GMT', '2017-06-01 20:41:41 GMT', '2017-06-03 17:33:17 GMT', '2017-06-05 12:13:21 GMT', '2017-06-05 12:16:25 GMT', '2017-06-05 20:28:17 GMT', '2017-06-10 14:19:52 GMT', '2017-06-10 21:29:37 GMT', '2017-06-16 07:26:04 GMT', '2017-06-17 03:31:37 GMT', '2017-06-19 12:12:42 GMT', '2017-06-20 01:42:28 GMT', '2017-07-01 18:35:31 GMT', '2017-07-02 23:14:19 GMT', '2017-07-11 14:29:22 GMT', '2017-07-17 18:18:19 GMT', '2017-07-25 14:37:00 GMT', '2009-08-17 10:34:59 GMT', '2010-03-02 07:41:10 GMT', '2010-07-02 14:43:22 GMT', '2011-04-16 13:27:25 GMT', '2011-05-25 11:57:45 GMT', '2011-08-17 14:37:46 GMT', '2011-09-20 14:42:01 GMT', '2011-10-17 21:34:30 GMT', '2011-11-01 11:08:02 GMT', '2011-11-16 18:34:25 GMT', '2011-12-05 00:20:26 GMT', '2012-01-06 05:35:32 GMT', '2012-02-18 13:30:37 GMT', '2012-02-20 18:50:31 GMT', '2012-03-23 17:33:06 GMT', '2012-03-25 15:54:29 GMT', '2012-03-31 11:00:12 GMT', '2012-04-10 18:44:51 GMT', '2012-04-24 08:42:29 GMT', '2012-05-22 16:50:37 GMT', '2012-06-11 13:49:18 GMT', '2012-06-22 16:12:52 GMT', '2012-06-24 15:27:29 GMT', '2012-06-27 12:24:34 GMT', '2012-06-27 19:04:32 GMT', '2012-07-07 22:21:41 GMT', '2012-08-01 02:41:03 GMT', '2012-09-07 20:17:26 GMT', '2012-09-10 08:24:35 GMT', '2012-11-09 14:55:58 GMT', '2012-11-21 01:11:07 GMT', '2012-12-09 15:35:54 GMT', '2012-12-13 22:42:07 GMT', '2012-12-27 00:56:58 GMT', '2013-01-04 09:38:37 GMT', '2013-01-04 18:32:00 GMT', '2013-01-16 21:34:06 GMT', '2013-01-19 12:01:41 GMT', '2013-02-02 18:58:36 GMT', '2013-02-24 19:06:48 GMT', '2013-03-04 07:23:09 GMT', '2013-03-16 19:38:59 GMT', '2013-03-19 20:44:49 GMT', '2013-03-22 05:14:40 GMT', '2013-03-22 09:16:23 GMT', '2013-03-22 23:47:17 GMT', '2013-03-27 19:50:03 GMT', '2013-05-01 21:09:21 GMT', '2013-05-08 12:54:53 GMT', '2013-05-10 09:51:37 GMT', '2013-05-12 11:47:03 GMT')
+
```

That is, why R console does not see it as a complete list (albeit longer), rather than waiting for more from input? I had to do the `a=c(a, ...)` to concatenate the two lists.

Comment: This is weird because, as far as I understand, `hist` passes `n` to `pretty`. But, if you run `hist(as.POSIXct(a,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT"), breaks=pretty(as.POSIXct(a,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT"), n=10))` then you don't encounter the error...

Comment: I think this might actually be a subtle bug (!) in that depending on how the breaks are specified they might end up being integers or doubles inside `hist.default`. In the code path the runs through `pretty` they are integers, which sets up the integer overflow when the numbers involved are large enough. I'd want to boil it down to something much more minimal, probably w/out the POSIXct stuff before submitting to anyone though.

Comment: `hist(as.POSIXct(a,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "GMT"), breaks="years")` works fine, and gives `9` breaks...

Comment: Related: [Error when generating histogram in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46767194/error-when-generating-histogram-in-r)

Comment: also, why the longer input causing R console to think it is expecting more input?