# Error integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))[1] NA in gapminder dataset

Tags: r, sum, integer

I was playing with the gapminder dataset, and when trying to sum the population, an integer variable, an error

`library(gapminder)`

```
gapminder %>%
        group_by(year) %>% 
        summarise(totalPop = sum(pop))
```

Shows NA as results

Then, if try

```
mean(gapminder$pop)
[1] 29601212 # ok, as expected
```

but if

```
sum(gapminder$pop)
integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))[1] NA
```

I read the [What is integer overflow in R and how can it happen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804779/what-is-integer-overflow-in-r-and-how-can-it-happen)

so, I tried

```
sum(gapminder$pop / 1)
[1] 50440465801
```

Any explanation why *sum* doesn't work, but *sum / 1* did?

In brief: why?

```
gapminder %>%
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(totalPop = sum(pop))
```

[image]

but

```
gapminder %>%
    group_by(year) %>% 
    summarise(totalPop = sum(pop/1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dividing by 1 coerces it numeric.

```
library(gapminder)
class(sum(gapminder$pop))
[1] "integer"
Warning message:
In sum(gapminder$pop) : integer overflow - use sum(as.numeric(.))

class(sum(gapminder$pop/1))
[1] "numeric"
```

Comment: thanks, makes sense. Anyway, any clue why sum(pop) gives NA?

Comment: sum(pop) gives NA because of the integer overflow.  I.e. the sum of pop is larger than range of allowable integers.  Numeric is not restricted like the range of integers.

Comment: thanks.  Learned that 

  .Machine$integer.max
  #> [1] 2147483647

Comment: Is there a more formal way to do this?  Dividing by 1 seems like a work-around.