# R not calculating large cubes correctly?

Tags: r

There's been some news lately about the discovery of three cubes that sum to 42. Namely, Andrew Sutherland and Andrew Booker discovered that (-80538738812075974)^3 + 80435758145817515^3 + 12602123297335631^3=42
(https://math.mit.edu/~drew/)

I was tinkering with this a bit, and I'm not getting 42 in R.

I do get it in other places (WolframAlpha), but R gives me this:

```
> (-80538738812075974)^3 + 80435758145817515^3 + 12602123297335631^3
[1] 1.992544e+35
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Is it a limitation with large numbers in R? Or am I (very probably) just doing something dumb?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

As pointed out by @MrFlick, this is a well-known floating point arithmetic [issue](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f).  R stores large numbers in your example as double precision numbers.

Also, be aware of [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow). See a related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804779/what-is-integer-overflow-in-r-and-how-can-it-happen). Note that base R **will not throw** an error (just a warning) when integer overflow occurs.The `bit64` package may help sometimes, but won't do the job in your case the accuracy it provides is still not enough.

Comment: Actually R doesn't treat very large numbers like that as integers. R will store that as a "numeric" value which is in this case would be a double floating point number (see `typeof(80538738812075974)`). So there is no integer overflow error message here. R will throw a integer overflow warning if you actually use integers (see `2e9L + 2e9L`). This is really more about the [well known problems with floating point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) which is shared with most modern programming languages.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for your comment. I edited my post and acknowledged your contribution.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to calculate with *large (integer) numbers* in `R` you can use the `gmp` library like:

```
library(gmp)
as.bigz("-80538738812075974")^3 + as.bigz("80435758145817515")^3 + as.bigz("12602123297335631")^3
#[1] 42

#or even better use also Integer in the exponent:
as.bigz("-80538738812075974")^3L + as.bigz("80435758145817515")^3L + as.bigz("12602123297335631")^3L
```

As @mrflick pointed already out you are using `numeric` - double. So the calculated result is approximately right. When using `Integer` you get warnings and `R` will convert it to `numeric`:

```
(-80538738812075974L)^3L + 80435758145817515L^3L + 12602123297335631L^3L
#[1] 1.992544e+35
#Warning messages:
#1: non-integer value 80538738812075974L qualified with L; using numeric value 
#2: non-integer value 80435758145817515L qualified with L; using numeric value 
#3: non-integer value 12602123297335631L qualified with L; using numeric value
```

Note that you have to give a `string` to `as.bigz`. When writing a number `R` will treat it as double or convert, as above, large integer numbers, to double and might lose precision.