# NAs produced by integer overflow

Tags: r

For the below code, I used [this file](https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/mFW8IEhc8Q4IA4a) unfortunately, I got an interger overflow. I followed [this instructions](https://koke.asrc.kanazawa-u.ac.jp/HOWTO/kmer-genomesize.html)

```
> spec1_25 <- read.table("spec1_25mer.histo")
> plot(spec1_25[5:200,],type="l")
> points(spec1_25[16:200,])
> sum(as.numeric(spec1_25[16:10000,1]*spec1_25[16:10000,2]))
[1] NA
Warning message:
In spec1_25[16:10000, 1] * spec1_25[16:10000, 2] :
  NAs produced by integer overflow
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804779/what-is-integer-overflow-in-r-and-how-can-it-happen might help

Answer (score 1):

Convert your columns from integer to numeric so that you don't get the integer overflow.