# Calculation of Cliffs delta with very large groups causes integer overflow

Tags: r, integer-overflow

In R, I need to calculate Cliffs delta. Here is the formula:

[image]

Where x<sub>i</sub> is an observation in group A, and x<sub>j</sub> is an observation in group B, and [x<sub>i</sub> > x<sub>j</sub>] is 1 if x<sub>i</sub> > x<sub>j</sub> is true.

Here is Cliff's (1993) non-mathy explanation:

> ...each of the n xs in one group is compared with each of the m in
> the other, and counts are made of how many times the member of the
> first group is higher and how many times it is lower.

This is then divided by the number of pairwise comparisons, i.e., the product of the number of observations in each group.

Here comes the problem: In my data, Group A has 66208 observations and group B has 228691 observations. 66208*228691 causes integer overflow in R.

```
set.seed(123)
a <- runif(228691)
b <- runif(66208)

x <- length(a) * length(b)

Warning message:
In length(a) * length(b) : NAs produced by integer overflow
```

Therefore, I'm not sure if I can trust the result of `effsize` in calculating Cliffs delta, as it throws a similar warning:

```
library(effsize)
x <- cliff.delta(a, b)

Warning messages:
1: In n1 * n2 : NAs produced by integer overflow
2: In n1 * n2 : NAs produced by integer overflow

> x$estimate
[1] -0.0005022877
```

I can probably find a way to implement the calculation without using `effsize`, but I don't see any way around the issue of needing to divide something by 15141173728 (228691*66208) which I don't know how to do, since it causes integer overflow. In addition, the numerator might also cause integer overflow.

Are there any way that I can be allowed to work with large numbers so I can calculate Cliffs delta in my data?

### Edit:

I followed Pbulls advice and found the part of the `effsize:cliff.delta` code where *d* is computed. `effsize:cliff.delta` returns a list of 10, and if the only thing needed i *d*, there won't be any warnings:

```
set.seed(123)
vector1 <- runif(228691)
vector2 <- runif(66208)

#Remove comments to replicate subsample sanity check
#vector1 <- vector1[1:1000]
#vector2 <- vector2[1:1000]

.bsearch.partition <- function(x, a, b = 1, e = length(a)) {
  n <- length(x)
  low <- rep(NA, n)
  L <- rep(b, n)
  H <- rep(e, n)
  
  repeat {
    M <- as.integer((L + H) / 2)
    left <- x <= a[M]
    H[left] <- M[left]
    L[!left] <- M[!left] + 1
    if (all(H <= L)) {
      break
    }
  }
  
  H <- L
  repeat {
    below <- a[H] == x
    below[is.na(below)] <- FALSE
    if (!any(below)) 
      break
    H[below] <- H[below] + 1
  }
  
  repeat {
    L.clean <- L
    L.clean[L.clean < 1] <- NA
    above <- a[L.clean] >= x
    above[is.na(above)] <- FALSE
    if (!any(above)) 
      break
    L[above] <- L[above] - 1
  }
  
  if (any(L == H)){
    H[H == L] <- L[H == L] + 1
  }
  H[H > length(a) + 1] <- length(a) + 1
  cbind(below = L, above = H)
}

treatment <- sort(vector1)
control <- sort(vector2)

n1 <- length(treatment)
n2 <- length(control)

partitions <- .bsearch.partition(treatment, control)
partitions[, 2] <- n2 - partitions[, 2] + 1L
partitions[partitions[, 1] > n2, 1] <- n2

d_i. <- mean(partitions %*% c(1L, -1L) / n2)
d <- mean(d_i.)

> d
[1] -0.0005022877
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804779/what-is-integer-overflow-in-r-and-how-can-it-happen you may wanna use `Rmpfr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logarithms are your best friend when dealing with impossibly large multiplications.

This implementation isn't *efficient* -- you might do well to copy a better pairwise comparison approach from `effsize` itself -- but it should be numerically fine up to `log(n1) + log(n2) ~ 702` or until the additions overflow:

```r
log.cliff.delta <- function(x, y) {
   ## bigger <- sum(outer(x, y, `>`))   ## Needs 113 Gb memory
   bigger <- sum(vapply(y, \(yo) sum(x > yo), numeric(1)))
   smaller <- sum(vapply(y, \(yo) sum(x < yo), numeric(1)))
   sign <- c(1, -1)[1+(bigger < smaller)]
   log_d <- log(abs(bigger - smaller)) - log(length(x)) - log(length(y))
   sign*exp(log_d)
}

## Subsample sanity check
effsize::cliff.delta(a[1:1000], b[1:1000])
#> delta estimate: -0.016404 (negligible)

log.cliff.delta(a[1:1000], b[1:1000])
#> -0.016404

## The whole nine yards
effsize::cliff.delta(a, b)
#> delta estimate: -0.0005022877 (negligible)
#> Warning messages:
#> 1: In n1 * n2 : NAs produced by integer overflow
#> 2: In n1 * n2 : NAs produced by integer overflow

log.cliff.delta(a, b)   ## is *not* fast
#> -0.0005022877
```

From this you can see that the warnings from `effsize::cliff.delta` weren't as concerning as you might think: it actually implements some clever matrix multiplication and averaging in calculating the delta estimate itself, the `n1 * n2` denominator doesn't come into it (and it's *much* faster than my naïve attempt).

I cannot speak for the confidence limits however, those may be affected to an unknown extent, but you didn't provide a formula for them & with these sample sizes any confidence interval is likely going to be so narrow as to be quite meaningless anyway.

**Edit**: Two additional points came to mind:

- after further inspection of the `effsize::cliff.delta` source this `n1 * n2` calculation is only used in downscaling a delta that is equal in absolute value to 1. I'm not sure what the logic behind this is, possibly to avoid division by zero somewhere, but that `NA` will then carry forward into other calculations so you probably won't get any non-`NA` results. The chance of this happening with such large samples is effectively zero though: one group would have to entirely dominate the other (up to machine precision) for this to occur.
- You can circumvent the overflow using doubles instead of ints, i.e. `as.numeric(length(n1)) * as.numeric(length(n2))` correctly returns `15141173728`. You'd be paying a larger precision price in the log scale anyway.