# C++ [Recursive] Write a number as sum of ascending powers of 2

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

So as the title says,I have to write a number as sum of ascending powers of 2.

```
For instance, if I input 10, 25 , 173 
10 = 2 + 8
25 = 1 + 8 + 16
173 = 1 + 4 + 8 + 32 + 128
```

So this is what I have done:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int x,c;
int v[500];

void Rezolva(int putere)
{
    if(putere * 2 <= x)
        Rezolva(putere * 2);

    if(x - putere >= 0)
    {
        c++;
        v[c] = putere;
        x -= putere;
    }

}

int main()
{

    cin >> x;
    c = 0;
    Rezolva(1);

    for(int i = c; i >= 1; i--)
        cout << v[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

I have a program which gives my code some tests and verifies if it's correct. To one test, it says that I exit the array. Is there any way to get rid of the array or to fix this problem ? If I didn't use the array it would have been in descending order.

The error isn't a compiler error. 
Caught fatal signal 11 is what I receive when my program checks some tests on the code

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://wandbox.org/permlink/aVdujjcJx0AZgHhX). What do you insert for `x`? What error message do you get? Please have a look on how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Provide example input and the expected output

Comment: _"... that I exit the array ..."_ Do you mean accessing the array out of bounds? To avoid that check `c` is less than 500 before calling `v[c] = putere;`.

Comment: You have come *very* close to providing an MCVE, but we need to know what the input is.  Voting to close until you provide it.

Comment: I insert the result. So if I insert 10 , i receive 2 8... If i insert 173 , i receive 1 4 8 32 128

Comment: Note that your array 'v' is vastly bigger than it needs to be.  In practise, 63 will be big enough for years.

Comment: ...  and what is the value that causes the problem?

Comment: I do not know which is the value. I can input number in the range 1 to 10^9

Comment: "To one test, it says that I exit the array." - what value did you give it when that happened?

Comment: @MartinBonner or `int v[sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1];` to be exactly the right size everwhere

Comment: 0 doesn't happen to be in one of the input tests, right?

Comment: No , from 1 to 10^9... I know that c shouldn't be bigger than 500 , but I think it cannot be that big since the max number which can be input is 10^9 which is way smaller than 2^500

Comment: @Caleth : *actually*, there could be an implementation where that is excessive - but it is unlikely, and it will never be insufficient.

Comment: @aerkenemesis I receive what I want for any test I can think of, but somewhere I am accessing the array out of bounds as user0042 said

Comment: @Vlad-Rares are you sure the input is from 1 to 10^9 and not to 2 * (10^9)? For any input higher than 10^9 the program crashes.

Comment: @pmaxim98 2 * (10^9) you are right.. Do you know what might cause the crash ?

Comment: @Vlad-Rares check out my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For values higher than 10^9 the program crashes so you need to change from int to long long.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

long long x,c;
long long v[500];

void Rezolva(long long putere)
{
    if (putere * 2 <= x)
        Rezolva(putere * 2);

    if (x - putere >= 0)
    {
        v[c++] = putere;
        x -= putere;
    }

}

int main()
{
    cin >> x;
    c = 0;
    Rezolva(1);

    for(int i = c - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        cout << v[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

All in all, a simple overflow was the cause.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked :) Can you tell me where I can read more about overflow or why it didn't worked in the first place ?

Comment: @Vlad-Rares [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641285/what-is-an-integer-overflow-error) might be a start, aswell as wikipedia's page about integer overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple overflow. And by the way a way easier way to do it is have a `long long unsigned int`

```
#include <bitset>
unsigned long long x = input;
std::cout << x << " = ";
std::string str = std::bitset<64>(x).to_string();

for (int i = str.size()-1; i >= 0; --i)
    if(str[i]-'0')
        std::cout << (2ull << i) << " + ";

if (x)
    std::cout << char(8)<<char(8) << std::endl;  //DELETING LAST "+" for non-zero x
else
    std::cout << "0\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

If you have a fixed size integer (e.g. `int` etc.) then you can just start at the greatest possible power of two, and if your number is bigger than that power, subtract the power of 2. Then go to the next power of two.

This is similar to how you would normally write numbers yourself starting from the most significant digit. So also works for how numbers are printed in base 16 (hex), 10, binary literals, etc.

```
int main() {
    unsigned x = 173;
    std::cout << x << " = ";
    bool first = true;
    // get the max power from a proper constant
    for (unsigned power = 0x80000000; power > 0; power >>= 1)
    {
        if (power <= x)
        {
            if (!first) std::cout << " + ";
            std::cout << power;
            x -= power;
            first = false;
        }
    }
    assert(x == 0);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Outputs:

```
173 = 128 + 32 + 8 + 4 + 1
```

Comment: A better answer than from campovski, but it just does the OP's homework for him, and it doesn't recurse (which is almost certainly a requirement).  You also haven't explained the problem with the original code.

Comment: Its just a general way to print integers, i didnt pull apart his code simply because it an entirely different approach, but easy enough to apply to get differnt results.