# Math in Java(Combinatorics)

Tags: java, combinatorics

My problem is:
[image]

My math formula is:
[image]
In this case X = N; Y = L;U = K;

```
    public class Play {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
         //n!(n−k−1)!
        int n = 10;
        int k =2;
        int l = 12;


        long result;
        result = (calculaFator(n) / calculaFator(n-k-1));
        result= (long) (result * Math.pow((n-k),(l-k)-1));
        System.out.println(result);


    }

    public static long calculaFator(long x) {
        long f = x;

        while (x > 1) {

            f = f * (x - 1);

            x--;
        }
        return f;
    }
}
```

It should be 721599986, but it is giving me 96636764160

I have some samples:

> With n=10, k=2, l=12 it should be 721599986
>
> With n=10, k=2, l=16 it should be 626284798
>
> With n=10, k=1, l=20 it should be 674941304
>
> With n=5, k=2, l=8 it should be 10800

Comment: so what is your question wrt java? is it not working according to your requirements? if your code is not working correctly, then you might want to add the expected results vs the actual results.

Comment: @AngelKoh just did =]

Comment: Have you heard of integer overflow?

Comment: Can't change my close vote now, but this is the dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2641285/2988730

Comment: @MadPhysicist, don't seem like an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The java codes is working according to your stated formula.
It seems like the formula is wrong rather than the codes. (or expected results or your x,u,y mapping to n,l,k is incorrect?)

```
int x = 10;
int u = 2;
int y = 12;
long numerator = calculaFator(x);
long denominator = calculaFator(x - u - 1);

int xu1 = x - u - 1;
long result = numerator / denominator;
System.out.println();
System.out.println(x + "!= numerator: " + numerator);  //10!= numerator: 3_628_800 
System.out.println(xu1 + "!= denominator: " + denominator); //7!= denominator: 5_040 
System.out.println("result1: " + result); //result1: 720 (correct)

int xu = x - u;
int yu1 = y - u - 1;
double remainderPlaylist = Math.pow(xu, yu1);
System.out.println(xu + "^" + yu1 + " = " + remainderPlaylist);//8^9 = 1.34217728E8 
System.out.println(xu + "^" + yu1 + " = " + (long) remainderPlaylist);//8^9 = 134_217_728   (correct)

long mul = (long) (result * remainderPlaylist);
System.out.println(result + "x" + (long)remainderPlaylist + " = " + mul); //720x134_217_728 = 96_636_764_160  (mathematically correct)
```