# Why (int)pow(2, 32) == -2147483648

Tags: c++, casting

On the Internet I found the following problem:

```
int a = (int)pow(2, 32);
cout << a;
```

What does it print on the screen?

Firstly I thought about `0`, 
but after I wrote code and executed it, i got `-2147483648`, but why?

Also I noticed that even `(int)(pow(2, 32) - pow(2, 31))` equals `-2147483648`.

Can anyone explain why `(int)pow(2, 32)` equals `-2147483648`?

Comment: The body and the title don't agree.. anyway, consider https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html and note the particular 'magic value'.

Comment: Glad the c# tag was removed. There is no pow there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an integer overflow error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641285/what-is-an-integer-overflow-error)

Comment: For c# we have similar behaviour: int a = (int)Math.Pow(2, 32);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming `int` is 32 bits (or less) on your machine, this is undefined behavior.

From the standard, [conv.fpint](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpint#1):

> A prvalue of a floating-point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates; that is, the fractional part is discarded. **The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type.**

Most commonly `int` is 32 bits, and it can represent values in the interval `[-2^31, 2^31-1]` which is `[-2147483648, 2147483647]`. The result of `std::pow(2, 32)` is a `double` that represents the exact value `2^32`. Since `2^32` exceeds the range that can be represented by `int`, the conversion attempt is undefined behavior. This means that in the best case, the result can be anything.

The same goes for your second example: `pow(2, 32) - pow(2, 31)` is simply the `double` representation of `2^31`, which (just barely) exceeds the range that can be represented by a 32-bit `int`.

The correct way to do this would be to convert to a large enough integral type, e.g. `int64_t`:

```
std::cout << static_cast<int64_t>(std::pow(2, 32)) << "\n"; // prints 4294967296
```

Comment: There is a proposal for the standard to make signed integer overflow well-behaved: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0907r0.html

Comment: I heard about that, but that doesn't apply to this particular example since technically speaking this isn't an integer overflow. In fact, even if the target type were `uint32_t`, this would still be UB.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you are seeing relates to using [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent 
 signed integers. For 3-bit numbers the range of values range from [-4, 3]. For 32-bit numbers it ranges from -(2^31) to (2^31)-1. (i.e. -2147483648 to 2147483647).

Answer (score 0):

this because the result of the operation overflow **int** data type because it exceeds its max value so don't cast to **int** cast it to **long**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << (int)pow(2, 32) << endl;
    // 2147483647
    cout << INT_MIN << endl;
    //-2147483648
    cout << INT_MAX << endl;
    //2147483647
    cout << (long)pow(2, 32) << endl;
    //4294967296
    cout << LONG_MIN << endl;
    // -9223372036854775808
    cout << LONG_MAX << endl;
    // 9223372036854775808
    return 0;
}
```

if you are not aware about int overflow you can check this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)