# Why does C# say that the fibonacci of 93 is less than 0?

Tags: c#

So I ran a code that generates fibonacci numbers
and when `i==93` I get `-6246583658587674878`. What is the reasoning for this?

-6246583658587674878

```
long fib(long x){
    long a = 1;
    long b = 0;
    long c = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= x-1; i++) {
        c=a+b;
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }

    return c;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 420; i++) {
    if(fib(i) > long.MaxValue) break;
    Console.WriteLine($"fibonacci of {i} is {fib(i)}");
}
```

Comment: Presumably that number is larger than `long.MaxValue`. You should read about "two's complement" to see why it's negative. You'll get a higher ceiling with `ulong` but you'd need to use `BigInteger` to go higher still.

Comment: OT in your last for-loop, you are calculating fib(i) twice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an integer overflow error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641285/what-is-an-integer-overflow-error)

Answer (score 2):

> if(fib(i) > long.MaxValue) break;

This will not work as you expected, when the addition overflows, the overflowed bits will be quietly truncated, so F93 (12200160415121876738) becomes -6246583658587674878. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#integer-arithmetic-overflow

If you want to compute F93 correctly, since all fibonacci numbers are positive, you can use `ulong`, the max value of ulong is 18446744073709551615 which is greater than F93.

If you want to detect the overflow, you need to use `checked` operator to throw an exception:

```
c=checked(a+b);
```

And catch it with a `try-catch` statement:

```
try
{
    fib(i);
}
catch(OverflowException)
{
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer:

```
if(fib(i) > long.MaxValue)
```

will never return true. This is because a long can never hold a value above long.MaxValue. Your best bet here to detect integer overflow is actually to do:
if(fib(i) < 0)

Long answer:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

A long only contains 64 bits, if  you perform a calculation that results in a larger number the result ends up looping back around.

So let's start by talking about unsigned long (which only holds positive numbers). This can hold up to 2^64-1 (or UInt64.MaxValue). If you have 2^64-1 and you add 1 to it you will get all zeros (plus a carry flag, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carry_flag, but that will be ignored in this case). Likewise if you have 0 and you subtract one you will get all 1s (ie. UInt64.MaxValue).

Now with signed numbers two's complement comes into play. The idea behind two's complement is: since 0 - 1 == 1111...111 then let's just say that 1111...111 represents -1. 1111...110 is then -2, 1111...101 is -3, etc. With two's complement the max positive number is 0111...111 (2^63-1, or Int64.MaxValue) and the minimum negative number is 1000...0000 (-2^63-1, or Int64.MinValue). Notice then that if you have Int64.MaxValue (0111...111) and you add 1 you will roll over to Int64.MinValue (1000...000).

So what happened to you is the factorial value got too big and it rolled over into negative numbers. There is a solution: remember that carry flag I mentioned briefly above? That can be used to continue the calculation into another 64bit register. I've never personally had cause to do calculations this large in c# but from a brief search it looks like BigInteger is what does this for you: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-7.0

```
BigInteger fib(long x){
    BigInteger a = 1;
    BigInteger b = 0;
    BigInteger c = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i <= x-1; i++) {
        c=a+b;
        a=b;
        b=c;
    }

    return c;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 420; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine($"fibonacci of {i} is {fib(i)}");
}
```